# how to get ModelState working on asp.net mvc web api?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rest, asp.net-web-api, modelstate

It is the first I have been using the asp.net mvc webApi, and I have Post/Put methods that has a parameter called ProductViewModel. Some properties of this ViewModel has data annotations to validate such as `Required`, `StringLenght` etc... I have the post method like this:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] ProductViewModel value)
{
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {
      // persist data here...

      return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
   }

   return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ModelState.GetErrors());
}
```

I have the `GetErrors()` method as an extension to get an `List<>` of my errors and pass to the client. My question is: Why the ModelState does not work?

if I pass null into a property of my ViewModel this validation simply does not work.  `IsValid` property is always `true`. Is there any way to work around this and get the ModelState work such as MVC ?

My Model looks like this:

```
public class ProductViewModel
{
    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Global), Name = "Name")]
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Global), ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required")]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Global), ErrorMessageResourceName = "Range")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Global), Name = "ShortName")]
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Global), ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required")]
    [StringLength(20, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Global), ErrorMessageResourceName = "Range")]
    public string ShortName { get; set; }
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you make sure that you are passing in the Content-Type as part of your request? (if content-type is not passed, a default value for the particular type is set and the model state would not be having errors...this bug has been fixed recently).

also, you could do the following:

```
return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, this.ModelState)
```

Comment: Yes, I have passing the `Content-type:application/json` by Fiddler, is it right? 

I get my object `ProductViewModel` constructed and filled with the properties but the ModelState.IsValid is always true, does not matter if there are properties with REquired is null, `IsValid` is always true. is it a bug of asp.net mvc webapi?

Comment: the content-type looks right...could you share how your model looks like and also may the raw request from Fiddler?

Comment: I edited my post, take a look at my model, only two properties with some validations. The jSon I have passing by fiddler is: `{Name: null, ShortName: ""}`, just to test the validations, but it does validate, I get other exceptions of my ORM's tools (nhibernate).

Comment: Hmm,I am unable to repro this scenario. I have the following: POST http://localhost:9095/api/sample HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Content-type: application/json
Host: kirandesktop:9095
Content-Length: 27

{Name: null, ShortName: ""}    Response: 
{"Message":"The request is invalid.","ModelState":{"value.Name":["Name field is Required"],"value.ShortName":["ShortName field is Required"]}}

Comment: I will try to exmplain my scenario for you. I have a  `ModelStateWrapperApi` and this class uses ModelState of my controller to do the validations. I saw here now using the ModelState.IsValid is comming `false` and it is ok, but when I initialize my ModelStateWrapperApi in constructor of my controller in my business class it does not work, I don't know why because I learn that the classes are reference type, so a I have the reference of the ModelStateDictionary in my wrapper but there, it is valid. Why? Can I initialize it on constructor and use it on Verbs Methods? (Post and Put) ?